# How to repeat a code in html without writing the same code again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I wish to show a given piece of code multiple times on a given page but I wish to minimize the redundant code being repeated everywhere (simple copy/paste) . Well I heard of people using Javascript or JQuery to store the given piece of code say HTML or CSS and than they use some simple div renders or the `<!--data-->` tag multiple number of times in wherever place they want the code to appear, which I have no idea how to use that is store a info in the scripts or html and then render it multiple number of places with a single div or comment.

Can anyone illustrate how to do this with an example. A bit more info on such tricks will be very resourceful.

Comment: Using server side script

Comment: write the code in a function and use it wherever you want!

Comment: Are you putting the code as just plain text or code that actually runs on the page?

Comment: I think what you required is a templates like mustache.js http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

Comment: If you do not mind using a server side language like PHP, you could create a `.html` or .`php` file containing the repeated code and then use `include('repeated_code_file.html')` at places where you need to paste them.

Comment: Thanks everyone I got so many awesome ideas to implement this ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at server side [includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Include it like this in your page :

```
<?php include ('content.html'); ?>
```

Comment: FYI, The question is not tagged with php.

Comment: Can I do it without php ? use divs or something for example addthis divs which can be rendered anywhere

Comment: No worries I am going to learn php next week so I will use this trick ! Thanks :)

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it :)... you don't need to learn php for this :) just use that one line with your file path ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple JavaScript code to repeat text: (which can be modified as per requirement may be to insert `innerHTML`)

```
function repeat(n,Txt){
    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
        document.write(Txt+ char(13)); //char(13) to draw new line
}
```

Just call this function as per requirement, on `window.Load` or `onclick` of a button..

Update: Check this fiddle to Enter repeating HTML [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/Vu9PA/3/)

Code for innerHTML:

```
function repeat(n,Txt){
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        document.getElementById("repeater").innerHTML = 
          document.getElementById("repeater").innerHTML + "<br /> "
           + Txt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of reusable code could look like the following (JavaScript example).

```
var application = {
    addition: function (sum1, sum2) {
        return sum1 + sum2;
    },
    multiplication: function (sum1, sum2) {
        return sum1 * sum2;
    }
};
```

And you could call it as follows

```
application.addition(5, 10); /* returns 15 */
```

Or more complexly

```
application.multiplicaton(application.addition(5, 10), 2) /* returns 30 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
<!--#include virtual="/menu.shtml" -->
```

It will support by most of web servers.

[More Info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Comment: Great I got the Idea! Thanks :)